# Why does this sort in Java not work?

Tags: java, arrays, function, sorting, program-entry-point

I'm trying to implement a short sorting algorithm, but it simply doesn't work. Anyone with more experience in programming got any tips? The array is not sorted, several values are coming up multiple times in the end print. Why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Sort the data
    int[] array = {1,5,2,3,6,2,29,-2,23,3};

    for (int i = 0; i<array.length-1; i++) {

        if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
            array[i+1] = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+1];
        }
    }

    // Print the data.
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(i+ ", ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you means by "doesn't work"? try to be more explicit. Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: Your sorting logic is off.  This looks a bit like bubble sort, but it only has 2 steps instead of 3.

Comment: Also this code doesnt compile.

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell us what result you actually get. One issue I see is that you are only making one pass through the array, while a bubble sort (which this looks like) requires a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your swap is broken. After you call `array[i+1] = array[i];`, `array[i] = array[i+1];` does nothing because `array[i+1]` is overwritten. You need to store the value in a temporary variable:

```
int temp = array[i+1];
array[i+1] = array[i];
array[i] = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
array[i+1] = array[i];
array[i] = array[i+1];
```

You must store the value in a temporary variable, as in the second line you get the same value.

Try with this

```
int tmp = array[i];
array[i] = array[i+1];
array[i+1] = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Several points. See if below helps :

1. There should be few compilation problems - semi colon missing, trying length() on array than length.
   2. In the end, you simply print i from 0 to array length. I suppose you want to print array[i].
    3. There are multiple sorting algorithm which you can find by googling.
   4. If you choose bubble sort, try with two loops, one outer till length of array and one inner, till (array length-elements already sorted). And inside you compare using temp variable.

   ```
               temp = array[j];  
               array[j] = array[j+1];  
               array[j+1] = temp;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1 if you want to swap two element please use temporary variable

```
public void swap(int[] nums,int i,int j)
{ int tmp=nums][i]; 
  nums[i]=nums[j];
   nums[j]=tmp;
}
```

2 this way which you display can't sort the data, here is my way to sort data:

```
public void insertionSort(int nums[])
{
   int j;
   for(int i=1,i<nums.length-1;i++){
     int tmp=nums[i];
     for(j=i;j>0&&nums[j]<nums[j-1];j--)
         nums[j]=nums[j-1];
     nums[j]=tmp;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add temporel variable and return to the start of array after every swap

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Sort the data
        int[] array = {1,5,2,3,6,2,29,-2,23,3};
      int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i<array.length-1; i++) {

            if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
                temp=array[i+1];  //temporel 
                array[i+1] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
                i=0;     //to return to the start of the array
            }
        }

        // Print the data.
        for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(i+ ", ");
        }
    }
```